# How do I put data that I have fetched into presentable data? (Discord.JS)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I have been trying to figure out how to fetch data from a Coronavirus bot so that I can present data when the command is used, and I think I am almost there.

I was having trouble getting the data visible to me in the console, but it works now and the data i see in the console is :

```
[
  {
    confirmed: 4267559,
    recovered: 1540596,
    critical: 46945,
    lastChange: '2020-05-12T09:09:52+02:00',
  }
]
```

However, I am now having trouble putting this information into an embed and presenting it. More specifically I am not sure how to for example select "Confirmed" and put it into .addfield in the embed.

My current code looks something like this :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const botConfig = require("../botconfig.json");
const colors = require("../colors.json");
const tokenFile = require("../token.json");
const bot = new Discord.Client({ disableEveryone: true });
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  var result = await fetch(
    "https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/totals?format=json",
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      },
    }
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => console.log("ERROR!"));

  const answer = data;

  const coronaEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#8e2430")
    .setTitle("COVID-19 CORONAVIRUS PANDEMIC")
    .addField("Confirmed Cases", data.confirmed)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter("test");

  message.channel.send(coronaEmbed).catch(console.error);
};
module.exports.config = {
  name: "covid",
  aliases: ["rona", "corona", "coronavirus"],
};
```

This does not seem to work and either tells me that ReferenceError: data is not defined.
Looking forward to your help, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybeBetter use `request` for request.

> `npm install request`

```js
const request = require('request');
const botConfig = require("../botconfig.json");
const colors = require("../colors.json");
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const options = {
        url: 'https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/totals?format=json',
        headers: {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        },
    };



    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            let data = JSON.parse(body)
            const coronaEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("#8e2430")
                .setTitle("COVID-19 CORONAVIRUS PANDEMIC")
                .addField("Confirmed Cases", data.confirmed)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter("test");
            message.channel.send(coronaEmbed).catch(console.error);
        } else {
            message.reply(`can\`t get data`)
        }
    });
};
module.exports.config = {
    name: "covid",
    aliases: ["rona", "corona", "coronavirus"],
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this did work without any error popping up. However, I am not sure if **.addField("Confirmed Cases", data.confirmed)** is correct, since the embed shows up with "undefied" where the confirmed number should be. How do I refer to the confirmed object correctly?

Comment: Hmm, i think you need change data, like `let data = JSON.parse(res.json());`

Comment: This triggers **message.reply(`can\` get data`)** instead.

Comment: Hmm , so `res.json()` already return json data.
Try 
`let data = res.json();`
`console.log(data)`

Comment: Console shows **Promise { <pending> }** and embed shows up with undefined.

Comment: looks like res.json() return a promise. I`m edit my answer.

Comment: This does not seem to work either, the embed still shows undefined. However, I added **console.log(data);** after **.then((data) => {** and the console now shows the information needed like in my original post.

Comment: okay, maybe try use request library for this. It\`s must work correctly.